Angular routerlink is not getting the navigation id
I am using angular 14 and fetching the data from firestore.
However, for one of the routes, the id is not returned instead it returns undefined.
This is the app route { path: 'job-contact/:id', component: JobContactComponent },
This is the JobDetails template that is supposed to go to the job-contact/:id route;
<div class="page_bg pt-10" *ngIf="job$ | async as job">
    <a routerLink="/jobs-list" >
     
    <button routerLink="/jobs-list">Back to Job List</button>
   
    </a>
    <h1>{{job.title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{job.company}}</h2>
    <p>{{job.description}}</p>
    <button class="button my-6" [routerLink]="['/job-contact', job.id]">Apply Now</button>
    

</div>
<div *ngIf="!(job$ | async)">
  Loading...
</div>

That button should lead to this JobContact component;
  ngOnInit() {
    const jobId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log(jobId)
    if (jobId) {
      this.job$ = this.firestore.collection('jobs').doc(jobId).valueChanges();
      this.job$.subscribe(
        data => {
          if (data) {
            console.log('Job data fetched:', data); 
          } else {
            console.error('No data found for job ID:', jobId); 
          }
        })
       
    
    this.jobForm = this.buider.group({
      name: '',
      message: `I am interested in the position`
    });
  } 
  }

jobId keeps returning undefined. The url returned in the browser when I navigate to job-contact is http://localhost:4200/job-contact/undefined
How come I'm not getting the jobId?
I tried logging but it keeps retuning undefined.
Here is the appRoute structure showing I have added the routes;
const routes: Routes = [
 {path: '', redirectTo: '/jobs-list', pathMatch: 'full'},
 {path: 'jobs-list', component: JobsListComponent},
 {path: 'job-details/:id', component: JobDetailsComponent},
 { path: 'job-contact/:id', component: JobContactComponent },
 {path: 'my-jobs', component: MyJobsComponent},
 {path: 'edit-job/:id', component: EditJobComponent},
 {path: 'create-job', component: CreateJobComponent},

];

This is my git repo; https://github.com/muhumuzaa/riverjobs

Make sure that job.id has value in your JobDetails component, you can print it out with string interpolation {{job.id}}. It would be great if you could share the GitHub repository or create it in StackBlitz with the provided sample data. Thanks.

If your url shows /undefined then the 2nd snippet is irrelevant. You have to define jobId in the router configuration (RouterModule). Please share your router configuration so we can help.

I'm so sorry I forgot to add the repo, here it is https://github.com/muhumuzaa/riverjobs

@jaheraho here is the approute;
const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', redirectTo: '/jobs-list', pathMatch: 'full'},
{path: 'jobs-list', component: JobsListComponent},
{path: 'job-details/:id', component: JobDetailsComponent},
{ path: 'job-contact/:id', component: JobContactComponent },
{path: 'my-jobs', component: MyJobsComponent},
{path: 'edit-job/:id', component: EditJobComponent},
{path: 'create-job', component: CreateJobComponent},
];

@YongShun I am consoling the jobId from jobDetails and its there but I dont understand why snapshot is not picking it up in jobContact component.

Try to replace (old)
<button [routerLink]="['/job-contact', job.id]">Apply Now</button>

with (new ✨)
<button [routerLink]="['/job-contact']" [queryParams]="{id: job.id}">Apply Now</button>

If this won't work try this debug-setup instead:
<button [routerLink]="['/job-contact']" [queryParams]="{id: 42}">Apply Now</button>

Does it help?

Thanks but routerLink is working fine. The problem is jobId and data are not getting returned in the job-contact component. That's the challenge.

In your JobDetailsComponent, you are currently using the .valueChanges() You can inspect the Observable data returned via {{ data | json }} (in job-details.component.html) or your .subcribe() function, the id data is not returned. Thus, it will be undefined.
Instead, you should work with snapshotChanges() observable and transform the returned data with id as below:
this.job$ = this.firestore.collection('jobs').doc(jobId).snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(map((doc) => ({
          ...(doc.payload.data() as Job),
          id: doc.payload.id
        })));

Demo @ StackBlitz (Branch: yongshun950824/patch-77730)
Commit

Unfortunately, the stackblitz is returning a 404.
Still this is not returning the data. When I do console for the jobId in the job-contact, undefined is still being returned.

I'm completely baffled because when I console jobId in jobDetails, the id is there. Even in the url it is there but when I try to console that jobId in the jobContact component, it is undefined. I just dont understand what is going on. It is like the ActivatedRoute in jobContact component is unable to get that id.

Hi, try this link: https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/yongshun950824/riverjobs. Then you need to browse the code in job-details.component.ts. It seems like due to I am the (forked) repository owner, I can able to access the file directly.

Thank you so much. However, jobContact component is still not getting the jobId

Even this stackblitz doesn't nagivate to the job-contact/id

Hi sorry for that, I had update the answer, with the demo. Please ensure that you have selected the branch: yongshun950824/patch-77730 in StackBlitz
